# Will Google follow link if anchor tag content is blocked?

Tags: googlebot, google-index, google-image-search, alt-attribute

This is a followup on a question I was asking here: [Cropping images & SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57551/cropping-images-seo)

Basically, if I have something like this:

```
    <a href="<Full_Res_Image>"><img src="<Cropped_Image>"></a>
```

and `Cropped_Image` is blocked by *robots.txt*,

1. Will Google still crawl to `Full_Res_Image` and index that in its web search as well as Google Images?
2. If it does crawl to the full res image, how do I then set `alt` tags on the full res image?

If these are not feasible, then do you have any pointers on how to show cropped images for user/page-load friendliness, while still having Google Images index the full res image and not the cropped image?

P.S. The reason I want to set alt tags in (2) is for SEO for the images.

Answer (score 5):

> Will google still crawl to Full_Res_Image and index that in web as well as google images?

Yes.

> If it does crawl to the full res image, how do I then set alt tags on the full res image?

You can't but you can still use other indicators of content such as:

1. Use the `alt` attribute on the cropped image. By being the effective anchor text of that link it would be logical to assume it would confer meaning to the linked full res image.
2. Use the `title` attribute on the anchor tag.
3. Use [metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata#Photographs) in your images.

Comment: Hi John, there have been multiple tests to show title attribute on anchor tag is not used for SEO purposes though? Here's one: http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4265397.htm. Same applies for metadata I believe? I've added a note to original question stating that is the reason I want to add alt text. Thanks!

Comment: I have no doubt that is value for SEO is minimal at best. But it can still provide guidance as to what the content is about even while not improving the real of the anchor target.

Comment: I see, if so do you have any thoughts on what approach can retain the same effect that alt have on image SEO's, but in this scenario?

Comment: I did that in my answer

Comment: Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51080/is-image-metadata-valuable-for-seo