# Does Google read JPEG comments?

Tags: google, images

I usually add some description in the JPEG comment when I'm exporting images from GIMP. I was wondering if Google will read those descriptions and show the images when I search for their description.

Also what about other search engines?

Comment: See this related question: [Is image metadata valuable for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51080/is-image-metadata-valuable-for-seo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're posting to a site that actually transforms metadata into text on the page it's going to be such a low signal that I wouldn't expect google to register it (I remember seeing some photography sites that do this for metadata/geolocation info, mayyyybe flickr?).  Google tends to make text not visible to users very very low in importance for good reason (because it's then susceptible to abuse, like the meta keywords elements).

So in essence, don't worry about it unless you expect some actual humans to examine the jpeg comments and want them to see something.  So probably only in a pro photography context if ever.

Comment: Instead, provide a description alt, title and filename.